# Issue in decryption crypto.subtle encrypted text using RSACryptoServiceProvider

Tags: javascript, encryption, cryptography, rsa, rsacryptoserviceprovider

I am trying to use RSA public key using RSACryptoServiceProvider and use it for encryption through window.crypto.subtle but ending with Cryptography_OAEPDecoding upon decryption.

//Generating public key:

```
        var cspParams = new CspParameters { KeyContainerName = containerName };

        using (var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspParams))
        {                
            var rsaparameters = rsa.ExportParameters(true);

            var base64ModulusKey =  GetModulusKey(rsaparameters);

            return base64ModulusKey;
        }
```

Encryption through window.crypto.subtle:

```
var jwk_base64 = base64ModulusKey.replace(/\+/g, '-').replace(/\//g, '_').replace(/\=+$/, '');

window.crypto.subtle.importKey(
    "jwk",
    {   
        kty: "RSA",
        e: "AQAB",            
        n: jwk_base64,
        alg: "RSA-OAEP-256",            
        ext: true,
    },
    { name: "RSA-OAEP", hash: { name: "sha-256" } },            
    false,
    ["encrypt"]);

window.crypto.subtle.encrypt(
    {          
      name: "RSA-OAEP"          
    },          
    cryptoKey,                         
    inputMessageBytes              
  ).then(function(encrypted){        
    console.log("base64 encrypted text: " + arrayToBase64String(new Uint8Array(encrypted)));
});
```

//Decryption using private key:

```
        using (var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspParams))
        {
            decryptedBytes = rsa.Decrypt(encryptedBytes, true);                
        }
```

On trying to perform decryption using above method ending up with

> "System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException:
>   'Cryptography_OAEPDecoding'"

error.

Tried doing decryption with specifying algorithm like

```
rsa.Decrypt(combinedKeyByteArray, RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSHA256);
```

but ended up with error,

> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: 'Specified
>   padding mode is not valid for this algorithm.'

Thanks in advance!

Comment: and your question is... ?

Comment: @DarkSquirrel42, I ending up with  Cryptography_OAEPDecoding while doing decryption using above sample, Anything missed here causing this?

Comment: There are no errors or problems listed in your question, or any indication if it is working or not and if you are stuck or not and why you would be stuck. What part of DarkSquirrel's comment are you not getting?

Comment: Below is the error on trying to perform decryption, System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: 'Cryptography_OAEPDecoding' using rsa.Decrypt(encryptedBytes, true);      
Tried doing decryption specifying algorithm like  rsa.Decrypt(combinedKeyByteArray, RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSHA256); but ended up with error, System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: 'Specified padding mode is not valid for this algorithm.'

Comment: edit the post with error messages